# Creating a simple Sencha component using a loop

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

How do we substitute hard-coded data with a for-loop in Sencha ExtJS? 

Say, for example I've defined the following list:

```js
Ext.application({  

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            fullscreen: true,
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            data: [{
                title: 'Item 1'
            }, {
                title: 'Item 2'
            }, {
                title: 'Item 3'
            }, {
                title: 'Item 4'
            }]
        });      
    }
});
```

How to replace data to something like this:

```js
Ext.application({
    launch: function() {

       Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            fullscreen: true,
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            data: [
               for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                  {title: 'Item '+i}, 
               }
              ]
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really basic stuff - I'd recommend you familiarise yourself with the basic language constructs before investing time in a framework.  There are several ways you could do this...

see: [*MDN: A re-introduction to Javascript*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

---

***Simplest way***, *create your configuration data first and assign it to a variable:*

```js
Ext.application({
    launch: function() {

        var listData = [];
        for(var i=0;i<5;i++) 
            listData.push({title: 'Item '+i});

        Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            // ...
            data: listData
        });
    }
});
```

*... or for those times when you're in the global execution scope and you don't want to pollute the* `window` *object with unnecessary variables - or just have an OCD over "one-liners" - you could take advantage of an inline function / closure:*

```js
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    // ...
    data: (function(){
        var data = [];
        for(var i=0;i<5;i++) 
            data.push({title: 'Item '+i});
        return data;
    })()
});
```

*... or on occasion I've used the following because I think it looks neater (but that's subjective):*

```js
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    // ...
    data: Ext.Array.map(Array.apply(null, Array(5)), function(o,i){
        return {title: 'Item '+i};
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and for the tutorial. Yes, I will spend sometime in the language. I was just curious to see how things work.